# Creating gradients with Core Graphics in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have the following code to create a gradient (or start of one):

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];


UIColor *lightGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0f/255.0f green:79.0f/255.0f blue:91.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *darkGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0f/255.0f green:79.0f/255.0f blue:91.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Why does this line give me "Expected identifier"?

```
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[lightGreen.CGColor]];
```

Comment: Be aware that iOS7 and Xcode 5 are still covered by a NDA, which restricts you from talking about it outside of the official Apple Developers Forum.

Comment: gradient.colors = may be it has to hold more than one color; like `gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor].CGColor],(id)[[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to many `[` in your code and you are not closing with `, nil`:

```
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[lightGreen.CGColor]];
```

Should be:

```
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)lightGreen.CGColor, nil];
```

Or even:

```
gradient.colors = @[(id)lightGreen.CGColor];
```

Comment: It crashes on the gradient.colors line

Comment: Well you array declaration was wrong so that could be why it was crashing on on the `gradient.colors` line. I do not see anything wrong with the rest of the code you posted.